# Raspberry pi 4 vlc isn't giving out audio

Tags: audio-playback, pulseaudio, vlc

The **below is the terminal log** when I ran vlc. Could any one help me whats the issue here.

I'm **able to hear audio from youtube in chrome but not through vlc when i play file**. Video is fine.

The issue started after I tried to check a usb web cam on the pi. Tried rebooting and upgrading no luck.

```
pi@raspberrypi:/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_audio $ vlc /home/pi/Downloads/4_6019518496386319852.mkv
VLC media player 3.0.10 Vetinari (revision 3.0.10-0-g7f145afa84)
[00311b58] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin
qt5ct: D-Bus global menu: no
qt5ct: D-Bus system tray: no
[99f87010] mmal_avcodec decoder: Looking for HEVC decoder 'hevc'
mmal: mmal_vc_port_info_set: failed to set port info (2:0): EINVAL
mmal: mmal_vc_port_set_format: mmal_vc_port_info_set failed 0x8b9317b0 (EINVAL)
[99f87010] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed for 17160001: no reference clock
[99f87010] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 0 for MMAL avcodec
[99f87010] mmal_avcodec decoder error: CMA buf pool alloc buf failed
rpi_get_display_buffer: Failed to get buffer from pool
[hevc @ 0x98961410] Failed to allocate output frame
[hevc @ 0x98961410] hardware accelerator failed to decode picture
[99f87010] mmal_avcodec decoder error: CMA buf pool alloc buf failed
rpi_get_display_buffer: Failed to get buffer from pool
```

Comment: VLC is very laggy. SMPLAYER is a good player in Raspbian.

Answer (score 0):

i removed vlc by

```
sudo apt-get remove vlc
sudo apt-get purge vlc-data
```

and then installed vlc, 
baam its working fine now

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.